# unit testing callbackFlow

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a callback based API like this:

```
  class CallbackApi {
    fun addListener(callback: Callback) {
      // todo
    }

    fun removeListener(callback: Callback) {
      // todo
    }

    interface Callback {
      fun onResult(result: Int)
    }
  }
```

and an extension function which converts the API into a <strike>hot</strike> cold flow:

```
  fun CallbackApi.toFlow() = callbackFlow<Int> {
    val callback = object : CallbackApi.Callback {
      override fun onResult(result: Int) {
        trySendBlocking(result)
      }
    }
    addListener(callback)
    awaitClose { removeListener(callback) }
  }
```

Would you mind suggesting how to write a unit test which ensures that the API is correctly converted to a hot flow?

Here is my attempt. By trial and error, I came up with this solution.

```
  @Test
  fun callbackFlowTest() = runBlocking {
    val callbackApi = mockk<CallbackApi>()
    val callbackSlot = slot<CallbackApi.Callback>()
    every { callbackApi.addListener(capture(callbackSlot)) } just Runs
    every { callbackApi.removeListener(any()) } just Runs
    val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val flow: Flow<Int> = callbackApi.toFlow().onEach { list.add(it) }
    val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(this.coroutineContext + SupervisorJob())
    flow.launchIn(coroutineScope)
    yield()
    launch {
      callbackSlot.captured.onResult(10)
      callbackApi.removeListener(mockk()) // this was a misunderstanding
    }.join()
    assert(list.single() == 10)
  }
```

But I don't understand two pieces of this solution.

1- In the absence of that `SupervisorJob()`, it appears that test will never end. Maybe collecting the flow never ends for some reason, which I don't understand. I'm feeding captured callback in a separate coroutine.

2- If I remove the `launch` body which `callbackSlot.captured.onResult(10)` is inside it, test will fail with this error `UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property captured has not been initialized`. I would think that `yield` should start the flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and an extension function which converts the API into a hot flow

This extension looks correct, however the flow is not hot (nor should it be). It only registers a callback when an actual collection starts, and unregisters when the collector is cancelled (this includes when the collector uses terminal operators that limit the number of items, such as `.first()` or `.take(n)`).

This is quite an important note to keep in mind for your other questions.

> In the absence of that SupervisorJob(), it appears that test will never end. Maybe collecting the flow never ends for some reason, which I don't understand

As mentioned above, due to how the flow is constructed (and how the `CallbackApi` works), the flow collection cannot end by decision of the producer (the callback API). It can only stop by cancellation of the collector, which will also unregister the correponding callback (which is good).

The reason your custom job allows the test to end is probably because you're escaping structured concurrency by overriding the job in the context by a custom one that doesn't have that current job as parent. However you're likely still leaking that neverending coroutine from the scope that is never cancelled.

> I'm feeding captured callback in a separate coroutine.

And that's correct, although I don't understand why you call `removeListener` from this separate coroutine. What callback are you unregistering here? Note that this also cannot have any effect on the flow, because even if you could unregister the callback that was created in the `callbackFlow` builder, it wouldn't magically close the channel of the `callbackFlow`, so the flow wouldn't end anyway (which I'm assuming is what you tried to do here).

Also, unregistering the callback from outside would prevent you from checking it was actually unregistered by your production code.

> 2- If I remove the launch body which callbackSlot.captured.onResult(10) is inside it, test will fail with this error UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property captured has not been initialized. I would think that yield should start the flow.

`yield()` is quite brittle. If you use it, you must be very conscious about how the code of each concurrent coroutine is currently written. The reason it's brittle is that it will only yield the thread to other coroutines until the next suspension point. You can't predict which coroutine will be executed when yielding, neither can you predict which one the thread will resume after reaching the suspension point. If there are a couple suspensions, all bets are off. If there are other running coroutines, all bets are off too.

A better approach is to use `kotlinx-coroutines-test` which provides utilities like `advanceUntilIdle` which makes sure other coroutines are all done or waiting on a suspension point.

---

Now how to fix this test? I can't test anything right now, but I would probably approach it this way:

- use `runTest` from `kotlinx-coroutines-test` instead of `runBlocking` to control better when other coroutines run (and wait for instance for the flow collection to do something)
- start the flow collection in a coroutine (just `launch`/`launchIn(this)` without custom scope) and keep a handle to the launched `Job` (return value of `launch`/`launchIn`)
- call the captured callback with a value, `advanceUntilIdle()` to ensure the flow collector's coroutine can handle it, and then assert that the list got the element (note: since everything is single threaded and the callback is not suspending, this would deadlock if there was no buffer, but `callbackFlow` uses a default buffer so it should be fine)
- optional: repeat the above several times with different values and confirm they are collected by the flow
- cancel the collection job, `advanceUntilIdle()`, and then test that the callback was unregistered (I'm not a Mockk expert, but there should be something to check that `removeListener` was called)

Note: maybe I'm old school but if your `CallbackApi` is an interface (it's a class in your example, but I'm not sure to which extent it reflects the reality), I'd rather implement a mock manually using a channel to simulate events and assert expectations. I find it easier to reason about and to debug. Here is [an example of what I mean](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/krossbow/blob/main/krossbow-websocket-test/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/hildan/krossbow/websocket/test/WebSocketConnectionMock.kt)

Comment: I found your guides very useful, thank you @Joffrey
I will post an answer based on those.

Comment: I meant to type `cold` flow and not `hot` flow! Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution I found based on @Joffrey useful guides:

```
  @Test
  fun callbackFlowTestSolution() = runTest {
    val callbackApi = mockk<CallbackApi>()
    val callbackSlot = slot<CallbackApi.Callback>()
    every { callbackApi.addListener(capture(callbackSlot)) } just Runs
    every { callbackApi.removeListener(any()) } just Runs
    val itemsToSend = Array(9) { index -> index } // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    val collectedItems = mutableListOf<Int>()

    val flow: Flow<Int> = callbackApi.toFlow().onEach { collectedItems.add(it) }
    val collectJob = launch { flow.collect() }
    advanceUntilIdle() // wait for callbackFlow builder to call addListener
    itemsToSend.forEach { callbackSlot.captured.onResult(it) }
    advanceUntilIdle() // wait for flow collection
    collectJob.cancel()
    advanceUntilIdle() // wait for awaitClose

    verify { callbackApi.removeListener(callbackSlot.captured) }
    assertArrayEquals(itemsToSend.toIntArray(), collectedItems.toIntArray())
  }
```

Please consider upgrading to `kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.0` to use `runTest`. In older versions we can use `runBlockingTest`, but it's deprecated.

---

**UPDATE**:
If you want to check that the flow can collect items one by one

```
  @Test
  fun callbackFlowTestSolution() = runTest {
    val callbackApi = mockk<CallbackApi>()
    val callbackSlot = slot<CallbackApi.Callback>()
    every { callbackApi.addListener(capture(callbackSlot)) } just Runs
    every { callbackApi.removeListener(any()) } just Runs
    val itemsToSend = Array(9) { index -> index } // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    var lastCollectedItem: Int? = null

    val flow: Flow<Int> = callbackApi.toFlow().onEach { lastCollectedItem = it }
    val collectJob = launch { flow.collect() }
    advanceUntilIdle() // wait for callbackFlow builder to call addListener
    itemsToSend.forEach {
      callbackSlot.captured.onResult(it)
      advanceUntilIdle() // wait for flow collection
      
      assertEquals(it, lastCollectedItem)
    }
    collectJob.cancel()
    advanceUntilIdle() // wait for awaitClose

    verify { callbackApi.removeListener(callbackSlot.captured) }
  }
```

Comment: This is almost what I had in mind, thanks for putting it in code. The only missing piece is checking the elements are actually in the list after calling the callback. This way you can check that the flow can actually collect items one by one, and doesn't need to build the full list

Comment: Hmm sounds good. I've updated the solution to cover that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Solution based on @Joffrey's and @Fartab's answers but using the [Turbine Flow testing library](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine), which further reduces the amount of code necessary. The important call here is once again the `advanceUntilIdle()` before calling the captured slot.

```
@Test
fun callbackFlowTestSolutionWithTurbine() = runTest {
    val callbackApi = mockk<CallbackApi>()
    val callbackSlot = slot<CallbackApi.Callback>()
    justRun { callbackApi.addListener(capture(callbackSlot)) }
    justRun { callbackApi.removeListener(any()) }
    val itemsToSend = Array(9) { index -> index } // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    callbackApi.toFlow().test{
        advanceUntilIdle() // wait for callbackFlow builder to call addListener
        itemsToSend.forEach {
            callbackSlot.captured.onResult(it)
            assertEquals(it, awaitItem())
        }
    }
    verify { callbackApi.removeListener(callbackSlot.captured) }
}
```